# Explanation of ''if $X\subset \mbox{dom f}$ then $f(A)\neq \{y:\mbox{for some } x, x\in X \mbox{ and } y=f(x)\}$''

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The sentence of the title is written in J.L. Kelley's book *General Topology*, page 261 (at the appendix) and said:

> It is to be noticed that if $X$ is a subset of the domain of $f$ then $f(X)$ is not
>
> $$\{y:\mbox{for some } x, x\in X \mbox{ and } y=f(x)\}, \tag{1}$$

but I'm not sure about the reason. I suppose it is related to the definition of $f(x)$:

$$ f(x)=\bigcap\{y:(x,y)\in f\}. \tag{2} $$

My unique idea is that (1) needs to be change to

$$
\{y:\mbox{for some } x, x\in X \mbox{ and } (x,y)\in f\}.
$$

Is right my ''solution''?

PD: I must confess I'm quite confussed about $f(x)$ notation. Because sometimes I read $f(x)=y$ was a notation to know $(x,y)\in $, as long as $x\mathcal R y$ to $(x,y)\in \mathcal R$. Is that possible from a rigorous point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While $f(A)$ is a very common abuse of notation, Kelley uses the notation $f[A]$ for the *image set* of $A$. See p.11.

Comment: Oh, so the above comment only is a notice. I mean, that $f(X)$ is not going to be used, that he will use $f[X]$? And that $f(X)$ is simply ''empty''?

Comment: @Dog_69, yes. Surely a more explicit clarification would have been nice. And when $x\not\in\hbox{dom}(f)$, $f(x)$ is actually... the universe!!!

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I think  this is the fact distinguish $f(x)$ in the sense of (2) between the notation $y=f(x)$ for $(x,y)\in f$. The second only has sense (in my opinion) when $x\in\mbox{dom } f$, while $f(x)$ is perfectly defined always. I'm right?

Comment: @Dog_69, right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very useful.